Under Windows 11: Problems with files that can only be stored under another name or in another folder after editing
I have just bought and used a few days a computer that has Windows 11 Pro (64 bit) as operating system installed. (Not by myself, because it's second hand.)
When I want to store certain files after editing one of them (I mean here an OpenOffice text or table file, but other file types might be concerned too, for instance MS Office files when I open them with OpenOffice - I currently don't own an MS Office software -, but completely different files might be too, I don't know yet) it seems that I cannot do it without making a new file - in other words I have to use "save as ..." - I didn't try yet to do this using the same name & folder for the "new" file - which should produce the question if I want to overwrite the existing after which the answer 'yes' could produce the desired effect. I have decades of experience with Windows versions from 3.1 through 95, 98, XP, Vista, Win 7 and 10 and never encountered such a problem without obvious reasons. After a few things that I saw concerning files in Windows 11, this OS (although according to some people supposed to be little more than a new version of Windows 10) has made a HUGE change in the way files are working when edited: the concept of 'file history' seems to come in here. There is now an option (in some cases at least) to ask for the previous version of a file ... in a case where I tried it, the system told me that there exists NO previous version of my file, but may-be this concerned only STORED versions, in other words ignored the new not yet saved version.
I guess that this new handling of files creates incompatibilities with programs used to edit and then save the files concerned, when these programs are not in a new version for Win 11 ?? How can I - supposing the conjectures I make here are valid - find what is the status of the file as far as plays a role in this question? What are all the possible reasons for the deactivation of the normal (re-) save function of a file the content of which one has edited?
Important: nearly all files I wanted to modify come from my old computer (which has Win 10) from which I transferred them via a DVD. But the problem occurs also in some cases with newly created files on the new computer. Apparently no problem with my accounting program although it must be older than Windows 11 ... (It has its own file versions management system: when saving, the old version is renamed with a BAK file type name, so that one has a chance to continue the work with the file if the new version is corrupted for any reason. But normally the BAK file will be overwritten when saving again after more editing. Therefore I don't understand why there is no problem with Win 11. Is the new system of file history not applied to cases where it might make less sense?)
Edit: The pretended existing duplicate of the question I ask here would imply having to redo a lot of work. I installed several programs that I had on the old computer, copied bookmarks for Firefox via the standard procedure written in the Firefox website etc. etc. And I doubt my problem has anything to do with changes by the manufacturer which is Fujitsu - like for my old PC, so I am probably already accustomed to most of them ... OK the changes by Fujitsu might be different on the new PC, for instance because it is Windows 11 vs. Windows 10 (in fact originally Windows 7 "ready for Win 10", but this might be unimportant).
As I said the problem might be with OpenOffice (it is quite possible that in fact no other program I am using is concerned) so I intend to go and look whether the problem disappears with the newest version of OpenOffice or Op.Off. for Windows 11 if such a thing exists.
The proposal to reinstall one's current Windows OS sometimes made by people at hotlines I consider to be a PUNCHing answer given for lack of an easily available better one. I 'practically' - may-be absolutely - NEVER followed such an advice. Even with one of these special orders by which they warrant that my personal data are safe, it is now just TOO LATE for such a 'solution' which I think might even leave my problem unsolved. I apologize here for having thought that the problem was essentially (or exclusively) a problem of Windows 11 while it might be a compatibility problem ... or - as I had it already earlier with my new PC - actually a BUG of Win 11 making vaguely similar problems, yes I know that because that one disappeared 'over night' after one of these quasi automatic updates of Windows, but this problem here did not [yet?] disappear likewise. May-be it is an affair of file options specific to Win 11. If I cannot solve the thing with another version of OpenOffice, I'll come back later ... with perhaps also already more knowledge about Win 11 - espec. where it's different from Win 10, may-be depending on a Win 11-option, either a new one or one that is much more in use than in earlier Windows OSs, as a default OR NOT
BTW I would be glad for a - preferably available on the WWW - complete document about was is new in Win 11. Thanks

First suggestion: you should "refresh" your computer. Windows 11 has built in methods of fully resetting itself to a clean and unused state, and you should do this right off. There's no way to know what the previous owners did, how the customized (or broke) the system. So, reset Windows 11 back to a default state, and the odds are very good some, if not all, the problems should be gone. And if they're not, then we'll know there are substantive issues that may need to be addressed then. I have suggested a duplicate with info on resetting your computer.

After a recent purchase of a "refreshed", and tested,  PC from a reputable company, I found it loaded with malware. It would be best to completely remove all partitions and reinstall Windows 11 pro from ISO. There should be no need to get another license.

File History has been a thing for 2 decades

In the case of potential malware, Reset from within Windows is a legitimate solution, since Reset downloads the image from Microsoft.

MAY-BE IT WAS JUST A MISUNDERSTANDING. I installed the newest version of OpenOffice. The problem seemed first to persist. But finally I discovered that - like for many other programs - the normal save is inactive when no change occurred since last opening of the file. It is still possible that the problem was real with the OLD version of OpenOffice - after all, why should I have wanted to (re-) save a file that I didn't edit?

With my edit of the question AND my last comment, my question might finally be useful . Please OPEN THE Q. AGAIN because otherwise people will not look at it.
